# I want to update + 1 in a column every time is plus + 1 in another

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I tried this way

```
CREATE TRIGGER ranknew
ON UsersChars
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE UsersChars
    SET rank00 = Stat00
    WHERE Stat00 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Stat00 FROM Inserted)
```

but so will all the data
I wanted it to be only + 1 at a time

```
USE Warz;
go
UPDATE UsersChars SET rankmonth = rankmonth + 1 where Stat00 +1
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Do you have any unique column on this table?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't easy but I think I understand your question.
If I'm correct, then you want to add 1 to `rankmonth`every time someone adds 1 to `Stat00`.

Assuming you have a unique column in your table (I've named it `id` in my example) you can use an after update trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ranknew
ON UsersChars
AFTER UPDATE
AS

UPDATE UsersChars
SET rankmonth = rankmonth + 1
FROM UsersChars 
INNER JOIN deleted ON(UsersChars.Id = deleted.Id)
WHERE UsersChars.Stat00 = deleted.Stat00 + 1
```

**edit**
here is the code from your last comment:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RankingHeroPK] ON [dbo].[UsersChars] after update 
as 
    IF UPDATE(Stat00) 
    begin 
        SET NOCOUNT ON; 
        Update [UsersChars] 
        set [UsersChars].rank00=[UsersChars].rank00+1 
        Where [UsersChars].CharID=(SELECT CharID FROM Inserted) 
        and [UsersChars].Gamertag=(SELECT Gamertag FROM Inserted) 
        and [UsersChars].Stat00 > 0
    end
```

this code is wrong, since it's assuming that only one row can be updated with any update statement. Also, the `UPDATE()` function does not guarantee that the column Stat00 was actualy updated. a better option would ve something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RankingHeroPK] ON [dbo].[UsersChars] after update 
as 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    UPDATE [UsersChars] 
    SET [UsersChars].rank00=rank00 + [UsersChars].Stat00 - deleted.Stat00
    FROM [UsersChars]
    INNER JOIN Inserted 
        ON([UsersChars].CharID = Inserted.CharID 
        AND [UsersChars].Gamertag = Inserted.Gamertag) 
    INNER JOIN deleted 
        ON([UsersChars].CharID = deleted.CharID 
        AND [UsersChars].Gamertag = deleted.Gamertag)  
    WHERE [UsersChars].Stat00 > deleted.Stat00
```

Note I've used inner joins both on inserted and on deleted.

Comment: but this way will not change the value of Stat00 right?

Comment: no, it will only add 1 to rankmonth whenever you add 1 to Stat00

Comment: I did not understand the part Id

Comment: You need some unique value to use for the join between the deleted table and the actual data table.

Comment: [code]use WarZ;
go
UPDATE UsersChars
SET rankmonth = rankmonth + 1
FROM UsersChars 
INNER JOIN deleted ON(UsersChars.CharID = deleted.CharID)
WHERE UsersChars.Stat00 = deleted.Stat00 + 1

Comment: use ` instead of [code]. generally speaking, you should avoid writing code in comments as it's not as readable as in questions or answers.

Comment: [link] http://prntscr.com/79l3rf   I would have to have the ChariD as primarykey?

Comment: I can't answer that, I don't know your needs. If it's guaranteed to be unique then you can use it as your primary key.

Comment: stat00 is a ranking of kills I wanted to create another monthly ranking, which would be reset every month, but the Stat00 continue adding normally

Comment: `code`CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RankingHeroPK] 
ON [dbo].[UsersChars] 
after update 
as
IF UPDATE(Stat00) 
begin SET NOCOUNT ON; 
Update [UsersChars] set [UsersChars].rank00=rank00+1
Where [UsersChars].CharID=(SELECT CharID FROM Inserted) 
and [UsersChars].Gamertag=(SELECT Gamertag FROM Inserted) and [UsersChars].Stat00 > 0 end `code`              its right?

Comment: now I got the error = Ambiguous column name 'rank00'. on `code`set [UsersChars].rank00=rank00+1

Comment: It is working now thanks, but sometimes the value of Stat00 jumps from 100 to 104 (4 killed with one shot) and rank00 is added another only one. how to make the changed value is added in rank00?

Comment: Edited My answer again.

Comment: now I got the error on line  `code`  SET [UsersChars].rank00=rank00 = [UsersChars].Stat00 - deleted.Stat00  `code` Incorrect syntax near '='.  http://prntscr.com/7aencu